# AUTODOCK software installation problem

Tags: command-line, icons

I am new user for ubuntu. I have always used windows but have very little knowledge about terminal and command lines. ((As I am a research scholar with medicinal background.) But I have been following this Ubuntu forum through out. And it helped me greatly. I am really thankful Ubuntu forum whole heartedly for this great effort.

Now, at present I am searching for a solution to a particular problem related to installation of AUTODOCK and AUTODOCK tools (ADT).

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. and I am using Synaptic package manager for installing different programs and applications. And I installed MGLtools, AUTODOCK, AUTODOCK tools package and it other files form this manager Successfully. and in the installed packages list also these are appearing.

but When I tried to launch the "ADT" or "Autodock" application I did not find the icon (as icon for "Avogadro" did appear after its installation). I tried launching it via terminal too.. but there it is showing 'command not found'.

Please tell me the correct procedure for installing this software. or where am I going wrong in installing the software.

I really need this application on my system ASAP. this software is one of the main reason Why I started using Ubuntu.

here below I have shown the Commands and their output from terminal. I hope It might Help to give better understanding of problem.

```
akanksha@akanksha-Inspiron-3542:~$ autodock
No command 'autodock' found, did you mean:
 Command 'autodock4' from package 'autodock' (universe)
autodock: command not found
akanksha@akanksha-Inspiron-3542:~$ autodock4
usage: AutoDock     -p parameter_filename
            -l log_filename
            -k (Keep original residue numbers)
            -i (Ignore header-checking)
            -t (Parse the PDBQT file to check torsions, then stop.)
            -d (Increment debug level)
            -C (Print copyright notice)
            --version (Print autodock version)
            --help (Display this message)


akanksha@akanksha-Inspiron-3542:~$ autodock-vina
autodock-vina: command not found
akanksha@akanksha-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

Comment: Which `MGLtools` package do you mean? I have 25 in my list.

Answer (score 2):

Your installation was correct. To see an icon in your launcher, you need a desktop file and certainly an executable file. To use the command line you need only an executable file. But there is a huge problem, have a look at the end of my answer.

1. The package **`autodock`**

   - Executable files

     ```
     /usr/bin/autodock4
     ```
   - Desktop files

     *none*
2. The package **`autodocktools`**

   - Executable files

     ```
     /usr/bin/autodocktools
     /usr/bin/autoligand
     /usr/bin/runAdt
     ```
   - Desktop files

     *none*
3. The package **`avogadro`**

   - Executable files

     ```
     /usr/bin/avogadro
     /usr/bin/avopkg
     ```
   - Desktop files

     ```
     /usr/share/applications/avogadro.desktop
     ```

     Therefore you can start it via Avogadro in your Launcher
4. The package **`autodock-vina`**

   - Executable files

     ```
     /usr/bin/vina
     /usr/bin/vina_split
     ```
   - Desktop files

     *none*

---

*Why I know that?*

Try the commands below, the lines with a leading `%` are the commands. All other lines are the output of the commands.

```
% dpkg -L autodock | grep desktop

% dpkg -L autodock | grep /bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/autodock4

% dpkg -L autodocktools | grep desktop

% dpkg -L autodocktools | grep /bin
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin/adt3
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin/adt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin/runAdt.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin/runAdt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/bin/adt4
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/runAdt
/usr/bin/autoligand
/usr/bin/autodocktools


% dpkg -L avogadro | grep desktop
/usr/share/applications/avogadro.desktop

% dpkg -L avogadro | grep /bin   
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/avopkg
/usr/bin/avogadro

% dpkg -L autodock-vina | grep desktop

% dpkg -L autodock-vina | grep /bin   
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/vina_split
/usr/bin/vina
```

---

**The problem**

After starting ADT via terminal with `/usr/bin/autodocktools` you will see something like this:

```
Run ADT from  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AutoDockTools/__init__.py", line 433, in runADT
    title=title, withShell= not interactive, verbose=False, gui=gui)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pmv/moleculeViewer.py", line 1026, in __init__
    trapExceptions=trapExceptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ViewerFramework/VF.py", line 387, in __init__
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ViewerFramework/VFGUI.py", line 444, in __init__
    verbose=verbose,guiMaster=VIEWER_root,)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Viewer.py", line 586, in __init__
    cnf=cnf, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Viewer.py", line 285, in AddCamera
    c = classCamera(master, screenName, self, num, cnf=cnf, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Camera.py", line 2189, in __init__
    self.AddTrackball()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Camera.py", line 2583, in AddTrackball
    self.trackball = Trackball(self, size, rscale, tscale, sscale, renorm )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Trackball.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.createSpinGui()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DejaVu/Trackball.py", line 726, in createSpinGui
    callback=self.setWithSpinGui,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mglutil/gui/BasicWidgets/Tk/vector3DGUI.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.createEntries(self.frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mglutil/gui/BasicWidgets/Tk/vector3DGUI.py", line 360, in createEntries
    self.f.grid(column=3, rowspan=3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2022, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .140381967613608.140381967671520.140381951084592.140381951131944 which already has slaves managed by pack
hit enter to continue
```

This seems to be a known bug in Ubuntu/Debian and I have currently no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Sir, the MGL tools that are installed with Autodock, I was talking about.  These are provided by "mgltools.scripps.edu".  Also I tried using the above commands but some "TCL error" is appearing while the program is about to launch and then its window closes.

Comment: Which command returns the error?

Comment: autodocktools command returns the "TCL error".    although initially after i give this command;  an autodocktools (ADT)  interface appears... then error shows in terminal and then that ADT closes.

Comment: Please help....

Comment: This is a huge problem and was not originally your question. :\

Comment: @ A.B.   actually sir (ADT/ MGLtools) and AUTODOCK is a complete package together to run the software. I installed it completely. but Now I learned that this "TCL error" is the Problem that is preventing the program from running.    Still Thank you so much for your time Sir.